# Change Related XML File Android Studio Java Class

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I'm new to Android development, and I'm having an issue where my `RegistrationActivity` Class is essentially pointing to the wrong XML file.

This is the error in logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at arufolo.myapp.RegistrationActivity.onCreate(RegistrationActivity.java:45)

I found that the error is caused by the following:

When I go to my Registration class and click the little XML icon next to the class name, it shows that the related XML file is the `login.xml` (My Login Screen)... Instead, I want this to show `registration.xml`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure that your Registration class uses the correct layout ID as the parameter to setContentView(). See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#load) for more information.

Comment: OMG I'm literally the dumbest person ever. Thank you so much @yole I spent so much time on this for no reason.